# "Access to fetch at '..." from origin 'chrome://...' has been blocked by CORS policy' happening in Chrome Extension background script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that is used widely by many users. One user wrote in today reporting an error with their extension, and provided screenshots for what looked like to be a CORS error happening in the background script.

According to the [Chrome Extension documentation for Cross-origin network requests](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/network-requests), this shouldn't happen as long as the extension has the right permissions:

> A script executing in an extension service worker or foreground tab
> can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as the
> extension requests cross-origin permissions.

In the section about [requesting cross-origin permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/network-requests#requesting-permission) it states that `host_permissions` needs to be defined in the manifest file with the right host.

My extension's manifest file has the following `host_permissions` defined:

```
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
```

According to [Google's docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/match-patterns#special), `"<all_urls>"` should work here by effectively requesting cross-origin permission for all hosts:

> Matches any URL that starts with a permitted scheme, including any
> pattern listed under valid patterns. Because it affects all hosts,
> Chrome web store reviews for extensions that use it may take longer.

Given that this extension has been live for a long time now, with a large user base, and this is the first time I'm hearing about this issue, I'm making an educated guess that it's an issue in Chrome.

I've asked the user to disable and re-enable the extension to attempt to fix it, with re-installing it as a plan B.

Am I missing anything? Is this actually a bug in Chrome or could there be other factors at play?

Comment: `chrome://` is not an extension origin, so the error is not related to your extension. If this is a typo in the question and the actual origin is correct, the user may have Opera browser that forbids access to the search site unless it's specifically allowed for this extension or the site may be blocked by a policy, which can be seen in chrome://policy, or the user has switched the site access of the extension to a different mode e.g. "on click".